# Стоит ли выделять слово "вот" запятой?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вчера я слонялся по городу в бреду безо всякой цели. Вот что такое быть сумасшедшим.

Предполагается ли запятая во втором предложении после "вот"? В каком случае бы она предполагалась? Это указательное местоимение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, запятая здесь не требуется. Данное слово является указательной частицей и, соответственно, обособления **обычно** не требует, даже если стоит перед относительным местоимением, обычно служащим для ввода придаточного предложения. Единственное, что хочу отметить:

**Вот! Вот человек, совершивший преступление!**
В данном случае частица вынесена в отдельное предложение и служит для эмоциональной окраски.

**Вот, я это и имел в виду.**
В этом же случае "вот" является положительной частицей, выражающей согласие. Пожалуй, единственный случай, где запятая может ставиться **на правах самого слова**.

*Примечание*: пример, приведённый Вами, как я уже отметил, является своеобразным исключением. Здесь частица имеет неразрывную связь со словом "что", поэтому не обособляется. В других же случаях, характеризующихся наличием, например, вводного слова, запятая ставиться будет.